# Resource Identifier Error

Tags: java, android

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
    android:text="Press me" 
    android:onCLick_2="onClick_2"

    />
```

I was creating a button in my Android application. An error came across with a printout of
"no Resource Identifier found for attribute onClick_2 in package android".

Can anybody help me out?

Also can anybody tell what do the last two lines of code infer (/> exclusive)?

Comment: You're supposed to use android:onClick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute name should be `android:onClick` and not `android:onCLick_2`.

`/` before `>` self-terminates an XML tag so you don't need `</Button>` separately.